# MySQL fulltext boolean mode search for two letter words with wildcards

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mariadb

I'm trying to solve a problem in which searches for short words don't produce results. I'm running MariaDB 10.0.34, I have `ft_min_word_len` set to `2`, and get the following results:

```
CREATE TABLE `ft_test` (
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
ALTER TABLE `ft_test` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`);
INSERT INTO `ft_test` (`name`) VALUES ('aa'),('bb'),('abc'),('efgh'),('ab'),('abcd');

SELECT * FROM `ft_test` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+ab*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- Returns "abc" and "abcd" but NOT "ab".

SELECT * FROM `ft_test` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+aa*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- No results

SELECT * FROM `ft_test` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+bb*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- No results

SELECT * FROM `ft_test` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+abc*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- Returns "abc" and "abcd".

SELECT * FROM `ft_test` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+abcd*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- Returns "abcd".
```

The manual says the wildcard `*` character can match zero or more letters, and indeed `+abc*` results include the `abc` row, and `+abcd*` includes the `abcd` row, but two-letter searches don't match the two-letter rows, and as far as I can see from the documentation, none of the above are stopwords.

Why is this happening? What's going on?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `ft_min_word_len` is for MyISAM only. Try changing `innodb_ft_min_token_size` and rebuilding the index.

Comment: @Vatev Yes, that seems to be the solution, thanks! I didn't realise there were separate variables for the different engines. If you'd like to go ahead and add this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.